# if -else condition is not working in node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, handlebars.js, basic-authentication

What I am trying to implement is that after logged in ,system will check user's role and redirect the user accordingly.
1- Admin
2- User 
role field is integer type. below is my code

```
router.post('/signin', function (req, res, next) {
    session_store = req.session;
    req.assert('Emailid', 'Please fill register Email Address').notEmpty();
    req.assert('Emailid', 'Email not valid').isEmail();
    req.assert('password', 'Please fill the Password').notEmpty();
    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (!errors) {

            Emailid = req.sanitize('Emailid').escape().trim();
            password = req.sanitize('password').escape().trim();

        var query = 'select * from userdetails where Emailid=? and password=?';
        var sql='select role from userdetails where Emailid=?'
            db.query(query, [Emailid, password], function (err, rows) {

                if (err) {

                    var errornya = ("Error Selecting : %s ", err.code);
                    console.log(err.code);
                    req.flash('msg_error', errornya);
                    res.redirect('/login-Form');
                } else {
                    if (rows.length <= 0) {

                        req.flash('msg_error', "Wrong email address or password. Try again.");
                        res.redirect('/login-Form');
                    }
                    else {
                        session_store.is_login = true;
                        session_store.user = Emailid;
                        db.query(sql, Emailid, function (err, result) {
                            if (err) throw err
                            else {

                                if (result == 1) { // facing issue here. It is directly going to else block though the user role is 1 in the mysql table
                                    console.log(result)
                                    res.redirect('/Dashboard');
                                }
                                else {

                                    res.redirect('/Audit-Record');
                                }

                            }
                        });


                    }
                }

            });
        }

    else {


        res.redirect('/login-Form');
    }
});
```

I guess I am making some mistake while comparing the result value. Can anyone of you please check and let me know where I am going wrong.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: There are tens of if else and which is not working among them?

Comment: if (result === 1) { // facing issue here. It is directly going to else block though the user role is 1 in the mysql table
                                    console.log(result)
                                    res.redirect('/Dashboard');
                                }
                                else {

                                    res.redirect('/Audit-Record');
                                }

Comment: @kingInTheNorth - The if else condition where I am comparing if(result==1) is not working.If logged in user's role is 1 still it is redirecting to /Audit-Record route

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved. Actually I was comparing in wrong way. we need to write it like this

```
else {
                        session_store.is_login = true;
                        session_store.user = Emailid;
                        db.query(sql, Emailid, function (err, result) {
                            if (err) throw err
                            else {

                                **if (result[0].role == 1)** {
                                    console.log(result)
                                    res.redirect('/Dashboard');
                                }
                                else {

                                    res.redirect('/Audit-Record');
                                }

                            }
                        });
```